# Inter process communication in UWP

Tags: uwp, tcpclient, tcp, tcplistener, asyncsocket

http://wikisend.com/download/880354/UWP_Server.zip

I have uploaded the Code in the above url.

Its a client and server application in UWP. Here both the client and server are on the same application and running sucessfully. But when the client and server are in two different application the Communication was not happening and unable to connect or send data. I came to know that UWP does not support IP inter-process communication on the same machine.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc9d5d6c-b5d9-4dfc-80a2-d5c6e3dfeded/uwp-why-does-uwp-limit-loopback-communication?forum=wpdevelop

Is there any way to communicate within two applications in UWP using socket programming.

many thanks
Gopi....

Comment: The link you posted already answered that question: No, there is no way to communicate using the loopback network interface. The link also gave you an alternative approach (see [Create and consume an app service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service)).

Answer (score 0):

In UWP the client and service need to in different machines for Interprocess communication.  The loopback exception allows the UWP app to act as a client to connect to the local service. The UWP app wouldn't be able to open a listener to receive incoming connections.

Outside of loopback, you could use a broker (again: still side-loading only) or go back to app services. It's not too hard to call an app service from an interactive desktop app, but I suspect it'll be tricky to call it from a non-interactive service.

see [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27c36ded-46de-41a7-bf29-0b410e6e1211/uwp-apps-to-communicate-with-host-processes-that-are-specifically-architected-to-receive-the?forum=wpdevelop]